# Augmenting algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am looking for an algorithm to achieve the following behavior. If summation of current and subsequent elements is smaller or equal to previous element then the summation is added to new vector. Here are the examples:

Ex 1:

```
original vector: 17 | 10 | 6 | 3 | 2
new vector:      17 | 16 | 5
```

Ex 2:

```
original vector: 41 | 15 | 10 | 5 | 2
new vector:      41 | 32
```

Ex 3:

```
original vector: 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1
new vector:      1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1
```

---

The code below works but there might be cases where this code fails. I am pretty sure than in a month I will forget the details of my own code. I would like to use a reliable code. Is there a standard algorithm perhaps in std or boost doing what I mentioned?

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>

void augmented_sort(const std::vector<double>& invec, std::vector<double>& outvec)
{
    if (invec.empty()) return;

    outvec.push_back(invec[0]);

    auto augment = [&invec](double& current, double previous, int& ai)
    {
        if (ai >= invec.size()) return false;
        int start = ai;
        current = invec[ai];
        int ri = 1;

        while(true)
        {
            current += invec[start+ri];
            std::cout << "previous = " << previous << std::endl;
            std::cout << "current = " << current << std::endl;
            if (current <= previous)
            {
                ++ri; 
                ai += 2;
                std::cout << "ri = " << ri << std::endl;
                std::cout << "ai = " << ai << std::endl;
                if (start+ri >= invec.size())
                    return true;
            }
            else if (ai == start)
                return false;
            else
            {
                current -= invec[start+ri];
                return true;
            }
        }
    };

    int ai = 1; // absolute index. start from second element.
    double current; 
    double previous = invec[ai-1];

    while (ai < invec.size())
    {
        bool success = augment(current, previous, ai);
        if (success)
        {
            outvec.push_back(current);
            previous = current;
        }
        else
        {
            outvec.push_back(invec[ai]);
            previous = invec[ai];
            ai += 1;
        }
    }
}

int main ()
{
    //std::vector<double> invec = {17, 10, 6, 3, 2};
    //std::vector<double> invec = {41, 15, 10, 5, 2};
    std::vector<double> invec = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
    std::vector<double> outvec;
    augmented_sort(invec, outvec);
    for (double d: outvec)
        std::cout << "d = " << d << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *but there might be cases where this code fails* - where are your unit tests?! :)

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I tested the code by giving different input vectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could be wrong, but your problem seems way too niche to have a standard algorithm.

However, here is some much simpler code which involves looping over the input vector once while keeping track of the current sum and only putting that in the output vector if adding the current element to it would result in a sum bigger than the last element added:

```
void augmented_sort(const std::vector<double>& input, std::vector<double>& output)
{
    if (input.empty())
        return;
    output.push_back(input[0]);
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < input.size(); i++)
    {
        if (sum + input[i] > output.back())
        {
            output.push_back(sum);
            sum = 0;
        }
        sum += input[i];
    }
    if (input.size() > 1)
        output.push_back(sum);
}
```

It would need some changes if you want it to work on anything but vectors in descending order (the requirements, as stated, seems to leave the intended behaviour for that unclear).